# libpcap: printing tcp source and destination ports

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, libpcap

I am facing a weird problem

retrieving tcp header and trying to print source and destination ports 
code :

```
src_p = tcp->th_sport;
dest_p = tcp->th_dport;
output  (in hex):
8e08 and 64a2
```

wireshark shows that the ports are
088e and a264

why is libpcap swapping the bytes?
or is there something wrong with my code?

PS: I am using structs shown in [this program](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports are stored in **network byte order** (big endian) in the TCP header (most protocols send multi-byte numbers over a network using big endian, hence the nickname).  Wireshark is merely converting the bytes to **host byte order** (big or little endian, depending on your PC's hardware, hence the nickname) when it is translating the bytes into human-readable numbers.  In your code, you can use your platform's `ntohs()` function to do the same thing.